# "Cannot read property 'transport' of undefined " in karma-jasmine Unit Test

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, jasmine, karma-runner

I built a project with AngularJs and made unit test with Karma and jasmine.
One of my controller in Angular project need to refer socket.io to transport data with server. And i wrote the unit test case for this controller. Ana add 'socket.io.js' file into 'karma.conf.js', When i tested it with karma, an error throw out:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'transport' of undefined`, this error throw in below statement in adapter.js in karma-jasmine node package:

```
var getCurrentTransport = function() {
  // probably running in debug.html (there's no socket.io)
  if (!window.parent.io) {
    return null;
  }

  var location = window.parent.location;
  return window.parent.io.sockets[location.protocol + '//' + location.host].transport.name;
};
```

i'm not quit understand what this code mean, i found that the `window.parent.io.sockets` is an empty object, so added another statement to return null so that it won't throw an error.

```
  var location = window.parent.location;
   if(!window.parent.io.sockets[location.protocol + '//' + location.host]){
     return null;
   }
  return window.parent.io.sockets[location.protocol + '//' + location.host].transport.name;
```

i'm not sure whether this change is right? Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: I am also running into this issue. Did you find a fix yet?

Answer (score 0):

@Zacho add these statement before `return...` in your **adapter.js** .

`if(!window.parent.io.sockets[location.protocol + '//' + location.host]){
    return null;
  }`

these just hack method,Although I don't think this is a good solution, i didn't find why this problem occur.